# Coding an IPNListener for Payapal in .Net why can't I get a response from sandbox?

Tags: .net, paypal

I'm trying to get a 'VERIFIED' response from the Paypal Sandbox IPN Simulator.
I've found and tried a number of samples and am unable to get any to work. So think I must be missing something pretty obvious.
Below is my latest attempt which I have tried both with prefixing and postfixing the 'cmd=_notify-validate' and with both ASCII and UTF8 encoding.
In all cases a get the string of parameters from the simulator but then get an empty resonse from the request.

If anyone can spot what I have wrong it would make my Friday.
Thanks

```
public partial class IPNListner : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] parameters = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
        string body = Verify(true, parameters);
    }
    private string Verify(bool isSandbox, byte[] parameters)
    {

        string response = "";
        try
        {

            string url = isSandbox ?
              "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" : "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            //must keep the original intact and pass back to PayPal with a _notify-validate command
            string data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(parameters);
            data += "&cmd=_notify-validate";

            webRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

            //Send the request to PayPal and get the response                 
            using (StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII))
            {
                streamOut.Write(data);
                streamOut.Close();
            }
            using (StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
                streamIn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { }
        return response;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK is me being stupid, set sandbox account to use my IPN listner and it works fine. Suspect I should be using a www.developer.paypal.com address when using the paypal IPN simulator. Code above works on the Sandbox I'm sure it'll work live.